# How can I deploy Archiva or Nexus on Websphere 8.5?

Tags: nexus, archiva

I tried to use Repository Management. I tried to deploy both but it cannot success

For Archiva

```
 It cannot read properties file.
```

For Nexus

[10/3/14 14:58:10:836 ICT] 000001fb SystemOut     O 2014-10-03 14:58:10 ERROR [Default : 6] - org.sonatype.nexus.webapp.WebappBootstrap - Failed to initialize
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.sonatype.nexus.log.LogManager
  roleHint: 
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PseudoPlexusContainer.lookup(PseudoPlexusContainer.java:108) ~[org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PseudoPlexusContainer.lookup(PseudoPlexusContainer.java:96) ~[org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PseudoPlexusContainer.lookup(PseudoPlexusContainer.java:90) ~[org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.webapp.WebappBootstrap.contextInitialized(WebappBootstrap.java:161) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1686) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:414) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1379) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2189) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:446) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:117) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:664) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:678) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:622) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1269) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613) ~[na:2.6 (04-22-2013)]
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:68) [na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613) ~[na:2.6 (04-22-2013)]
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287) [na:1.7.0]
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1256) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:252) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87) [na:1.7.0]
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1250) [na:1.7.0]
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1088) [na:1.7.0]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831) [na:1.7.0]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:804) [na:1.7.0]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118) [bootstrap.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf021412.02]]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602) [com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LocatedBeans$Itr.next(LocatedBeans.java:141) ~[org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LocatedBeans$Itr.next(LocatedBeans.java:1) ~[org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:76) ~[org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:1) ~[org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PseudoPlexusContainer.lookup(PseudoPlexusContainer.java:104) ~[org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.2.0.jar:na]
    ... 61 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0):

For Nexus it is not recommended to run Nexus on other application servers beyond the default Eclipse Jetty that is included in the the download bundle. Running Nexus on Jetty will be more performant and easier to manage.